# Micropython Raw Socket on MAC Layer

Tags: sockets, esp8266, ethernet, raw-sockets, micropython

How exactly would one go about creating a raw socket on the MAC layer in Micropython?

The UNIX equivalent is:

```
eth_p_all=3
netif='wlan0'
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(eth_p_all))
s.bind((netif,0))
```

For one, it is not clear how to get the interface name, and there is no `socket.AF_PACKET` or `socket.htons`.

So, if there is no way to do this with the stock libraries or firmware, which libraries should I choose, or if firmware modification is required, how exactly should I modify the firmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have no raw socket implementation at current upy firmware. Yo can check the following line. The raw socket dispatch has been removed from modlwip.c

https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/68a5d6fe7746850ce049b8bf295bfce1382383f3/extmod/modlwip.c#L712

If you want to modify firmware by your self, you can follow the steps.

- Check your platform's origin SDK support raw socket or not. (for example, cc3200 use TI's cc3200 SDK and it support raw socket)
- Modify modlwip.c

There's an unofficial port(realtek's ameba series) support raw socket. You could start from this one.

https://github.com/wylinks/micropython-ameba/blob/ameba/ports/ameba/mphelper/mods/modlwip.c